# Webpack not recognizing firebase.initializeApp() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, webpack

I am making a chat application with React and Firebase now, it creats an error, " TypeError: firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.initializeApp is not a function " I went through [this discussion][1] wherein it became pretty clear that it was related to webpack,

But I couldn't figure anything out ... I also thought of compiling it with babel, but figured out that that it would put load on the client-side which wouldn't be the best option...

My index.html has::

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.22.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.22.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
```

My firebase.js file::

```
import firebase from "firebase";

 For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp = ({
     apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
     authDomain: "xxxxxxxx",
     databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
     projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
     storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
     messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
     appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
     measurementId: "xxxxxx"
});
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseApp);
  firebase.analytics();

const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const storage = firebase.storage();

export { db, auth, storage };
```

Error:

```
    TypeError: firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.initializeApp is not a function
Module../src/firebase.js
E:/Final Site/UnderDev/chat/src/firebase.js:14
  11 |      appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  12 |      measurementId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  13 | });
> 14 | firebase.initializeApp(firebaseApp);
  15 |   firebase.analytics();
  16 | 
  17 | const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
View compiled
__webpack_require__
E:/Final Site/Dev/chat/webpack/bootstrap:784
  781 | };
  782 | 
  783 | // Execute the module function
> 784 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  785 | 
  786 | // Flag the module as loaded
  787 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
E:/Final Site/Dev/chat/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
Module../src/App.js
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:126:67
__webpack_require__
E:/Final Site/Dev/chat/webpack/bootstrap:784
  781 | };
  782 | 
  783 | // Execute the module function
> 784 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  785 | 
  786 | // Flag the module as loaded
  787 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
E:/Final Site/Dev/chat/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
Module../src/index.js
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:499:62
__webpack_require__
E:/Final Site/Dev/chat/webpack/bootstrap:784
  781 | };
  782 | 
  783 | // Execute the module function
> 784 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  785 | 
  786 | // Flag the module as loaded
  787 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
E:/Final Site/Dev/chat/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
1
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:641:18
__webpack_require__
E:/Final Site/UnderDev/chat/webpack/bootstrap:784
  781 | };
  782 | 
  783 | // Execute the module function
> 784 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  785 | 
  786 | // Flag the module as loaded
  787 | module.l = true;
View compiled
checkDeferredModules
E:/Final Site/UnderDev/chat/webpack/bootstrap:45
  42 |  }
  43 |  if(fulfilled) {
  44 |      deferredModules.splice(i--, 1);
> 45 |      result = __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = deferredModule[0]);
     | ^  46 |  }
  47 | }
  48 | 
View compiled
Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push]
E:/Final Site/Dev/chat/webpack/bootstrap:32
  29 |  deferredModules.push.apply(deferredModules, executeModules || []);
  30 | 
  31 |  // run deferred modules when all chunks ready
> 32 |  return checkDeferredModules();
     | ^  33 | };
  34 | function checkDeferredModules() {
  35 |  var result;
View compiled
(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1:61
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You're not really supposed to use both the script includes and a bundler `import` at the same time.  Pick one or the other.  If using webpack, you probably just want to remove the scripts and just use the bundler.

The Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#using-module-bundlers) shows you what you have to import to use the bundler:

```
// Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";

// If you enabled Analytics in your project, add the Firebase SDK for Analytics
import "firebase/analytics";

// Add the Firebase products that you want to use
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";
```

You should remove your import of "firebase" and replace with what's shown here.