# How to call a Cloud Function for Firebase in Vue3

Tags: node.js, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm following the Net Ninja's tutorial about firebase cloud functions and I can't figure out how to call a function from a vue component. (he doesn't use vue in the tutorial).

So I have this vue3 app with firebase functions installed in it. How do I import the functions into a component? I can't find the answer anywhere. I'm still learning to code and I still don't understand very well how to import the packages needed.

I have a index.js file in the functions folder with a few functions inside.
I now want to call one of them ( a .onCall function) when clicking a button in a component.

I understand I need to import something in that component but I can't figure out what!

Answer (score 6):

Your Vue.js app and your Cloud Functions for Firebase are totally different components of your whole application.

The Vue.js app is a **front-end component** (even if it is hosted in a cloud service like Firebase Hosting).

The Cloud Functions are serveless **back-end components**, hosted in the Firebase (Google Cloud) infrastructure and reacting to events.

To get these two components interacting with each other there are basically two possibilities:

- For Callable Cloud Functions and HTTPS Cloud Functions, you will call them from your Vue.js app.
- For background triggered Cloud Functions (e.g. triggered by a Firestore event like doc creation), the Vue.js front-end could generate the event (e.g. write to Firestore) and/or listen to the result of a Cloud Function execution (e.g. a Firestore doc is modified).

---

> How do I import the functions into a component?

As explained above, you cannot integrate a Cloud Function code in your Vue.js code. In particular you cannot "import the functions into a component".

> I now want to call one of them (a .`onCall()` function) when clicking a
> button in a component.

If your Cloud Function is a Callable one, you can call it through the JS SDK as explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

---

**UPDATE Following your comment:**

As explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), to call the Callable Function from your Vue.js app, you need to do as folloows (with the JS SDK v9):

Add Firebase to your Vue.js app. For example via a `firebaseConfig.js` file:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getFunctions } from "firebase/functions";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "...",
    // ....
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
const functions = getFunctions(firebaseApp);

export { db, functions  };
```

Then, in your component, you do

```
<script>
    import { functions } from '../firebaseConfig';
    import {  httpsCallable } from 'firebase/functions';
    
    // ...
    methods: {
        async callFunction() {
            const addMessage = httpsCallable(functions, 'addMessage');
            const result = await addMessage({ text: messageText })
            const data = result.data;
            //...
        });
            
     }

</script>
```

Comment: Oh oh.. I got confused and deleted my comment. Thanks! That really clears things out. I spent all day  trying to figure this out. I'm also learning how to use the firebase version 9 so I'm a bit confused... but I'm starting to understand better now.  Thank you so much for your help. I will sleep well tonight!

Comment: @Posoroko Glad I could help you! If my answer gave you the solution, please accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Should this work in Vue 2 as well? I've been trying to get my firebase functions to run in my Vue app for a few days now with no success. I've tried doing it exactly as your answer suggests, but I get the error:

TypeError: Object(l["initializeApp"]) is not a function. (In 'Object(l["initializeApp"])(N)', 'Object(l["initializeApp"])' is an instance of Object)

Comment: Actually the answer is for Vue.js 2. If you exactly follow the answer it shoudl work. Maybe a problem with webpakk, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64248604/webpack-not-recognizing-firebase-initializeapp-function

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. I tried the answer from the link you sent, but it doesn't work and I don't think it actually applies to my problem. In terms of your answer, my firebaseConfig.js is exactly like yours. But in the Vue component, as soon as I include the first line, importing { functions }, the component breaks and gives the error as I mentioned above.